# Curl F and conservative vector field.

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

If curl F = 0, is F conservative? I know F conservative implies curl F = 0, however, I want to know if it works the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on the other way only if the region in which  the vector field is defined is simply connected: [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields).